# static map initialization error - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dictionary, static-initialization

Using Visual Studio 2015, I have been trying load a table that contains floating point values for degrees converted to radians. Since the MathFunctions class is static (static functions), I am trying to initialize the map that withholds the converted radian values. But I keep getting **LNK2001 unresolved symbol error** when I reference the map inside the InitTables/Degree2Radians functions - Note that both the header and cpp files lie in the same project under the same folder "Utilities"

Declarations (MathFunctions.h)

```
 #pragma once
 #ifndef MATHFUNCTIONS_H
 #define MATHFUNCTIONS_H
 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
 #include <math.h>
 #include <map>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

namespace LookupTables
{
    class MathFunctions
    {
      private:
        static map<short, float>Degree2RadiansTable;

      public:
        static void InitTables();
        static float Degree2Radians(short angleInDegrees);      
};
}
#endif
```

While Definitions (MathFunctions.cpp) are as follows

```
namespace LookupTables
{
    void MathFunctions::InitTables()
    {
        // Load degree2radians table
        short degrees = 0;
        float radians = 0;
        ifstream infile("..\Tables\Degree2Radians.txt");
        if (infile.good() && infile.is_open())
        {
                while (infile >> degrees && infile >>radians) 
                {
                    MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable.insert({ degrees,radians });
                }
        }
        infile.close();     
    }

    float MathFunctions::Degree2Radians(short angleInDegrees)
    {
        return MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable[angleInDegrees];
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Are you linking with the place that defines `Degree2Radians()`?

Comment: @bobah - Linking? They are under the same folder and project. Not external.

Comment: @bobah - Just edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: you need to construct it somewhere : `static map<short, float> MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable;`

Comment: @UmNyobe - You mean at the top of the cpp file after header include directives?

Comment: Say this in the `.cpp`: `map<short, float> MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable;`

Comment: @bobah - Well I compiled now as per UmNyobe and bobah - But I dont see the purpose of a declaration in header file. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @UmNyobe - Put your answer and I will mark it. You came up first with the answer.

Comment: Declarations are there to let client code correctly refer to the externally _defined_ symbol

Comment: @UmNyobe - `static` keyword should not be used in definition (it means different things in that context.

Comment: Am sorry. my bad - It is not compiling. My apologies, the error is still there

Comment: yep copy paste mistake

Comment: Dont know if this is a compiler bug, but I tried to construct in the cpp file with and without the static keyword 
map<short, float> Degree2RadiansTable;  and    
static map<short, float> Degree2RadiansTable;   No luck

Comment: Compiler bug? Of course not. It's your lack of knowledge of C++. Like this `map<short, float> MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable;`. No static but don't forget the class name.

Comment: Sorry if the above seems rude, but it gets me when beginners say 'compiler bug'.

Comment: @john - ? Well ok not a compiler bug, but still not compiling.

Comment: @John - no problemo mate,

Comment: Well then you've made some other mistake. Please post exactly what you are trying to compile.

Comment: @john - Posted the whole code. This is a simple class, nothing fancy here.

Comment: @john - Bingo! map<short, float> MathFunctions::Degree2RadiansTable;  was the answer